# apt install fftw3 doesn't create necessary symbolic links, what to do?

Tags: apt, fftw

System:

Ubuntu 21.04 inside Virtual Box.

Running `sudo apt install libfftw3-3` installs the fftw3 libs, but doesn't seem to create the symbolic links for the system to find them.

In the below terminal output, I don't see `libfftw3.so` listed anywhere, and the linker can't find it anywhere.  Should I have expected the apt install command to take care of this for me?  In the short term, should I just manually create a symbolic link?  What link should I create?  I presume I it should be something like:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3.so.3 /usr/lib/libfftw3.so
```

anything wrong with that?

Here's the terminal output:

```
>>> find /usr -name "*fftw*"
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3f.so.3.5.8
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3f_threads.so.3.5.8
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3f_omp.so.3.5.8
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3l.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3_omp.so.3.5.8
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3f_threads.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3f_omp.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3_threads.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3_omp.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3l_threads.so.3.5.8
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3f.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3l_omp.so.3.5.8
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3l.so.3.5.8
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3_threads.so.3.5.8
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3.so.3.5.8
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3l_omp.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3l_threads.so.3
/usr/share/doc/libfftw3-3
/usr/share/doc/libfftw3-long3
/usr/share/doc/libfftw3-single3
/usr/share/doc/libfftw3-double3

>>> g++ test.cpp -o test -lfftw3 && ./test
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfftw3
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

>>> ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/*fftw*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      22 Jul  3 10:40 libfftw3f_omp.so.3 -> libfftw3f_omp.so.3.5.8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   31176 Jun  5  2020 libfftw3f_omp.so.3.5.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      18 Jul  3 10:40 libfftw3f.so.3 -> libfftw3f.so.3.5.8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2156872 Jun  5  2020 libfftw3f.so.3.5.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      26 Jul  3 10:40 libfftw3f_threads.so.3 -> libfftw3f_threads.so.3.5.8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   35368 Jun  5  2020 libfftw3f_threads.so.3.5.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      22 Jun  5  2020 libfftw3l_omp.so.3 -> libfftw3l_omp.so.3.5.8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   31176 Jun  5  2020 libfftw3l_omp.so.3.5.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      18 Jun  5  2020 libfftw3l.so.3 -> libfftw3l.so.3.5.8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  899392 Jun  5  2020 libfftw3l.so.3.5.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      26 Jun  5  2020 libfftw3l_threads.so.3 -> libfftw3l_threads.so.3.5.8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   35368 Jun  5  2020 libfftw3l_threads.so.3.5.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      21 Jun  5  2020 libfftw3_omp.so.3 -> libfftw3_omp.so.3.5.8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   31176 Jun  5  2020 libfftw3_omp.so.3.5.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      17 Jun  5  2020 libfftw3.so.3 -> libfftw3.so.3.5.8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2115912 Jun  5  2020 libfftw3.so.3.5.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      25 Jun  5  2020 libfftw3_threads.so.3 -> libfftw3_threads.so.3.5.8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   35368 Jun  5  2020 libfftw3_threads.so.3.5.8
```

Comment: Have you tried `g++ test.cpp -o test -L/usr/lib -lfftw3 && ./test`?

Comment: @WMRamadan, no I didn't try that.  I assumed that /usr/lib should already be on the library search path.  I'm not sure I'm set up to try it at this point